# Adding Textbox at runtime in Asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms, runtime

in.aspx page

```
<form id="MyForm" method="post" runat="server">
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>  
</asp:Content>
</form>
```

in code behind .cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Remove the session when first time page loads.
            Session.Remove("clicks");
        }

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowCount = 0;

        //initialize a session.
        rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]);

        rowCount++;

        //In each button clic save the numbers into the session.
        Session["clicks"] = rowCount;


        //Create the textboxes and labels each time the button is clicked.
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {

            TextBox TxtBoxU = new TextBox();
            TextBox TxtBoxE = new TextBox();

            Label lblU = new Label();
            Label lblE = new Label();

            TxtBoxU.ID = "TextBoxU" + i.ToString();
            TxtBoxE.ID = "TextBoxE" + i.ToString();

            lblU.ID = "LabelU" + i.ToString();
            lblE.ID = "LabelE" + i.ToString();


            lblU.Text = "User " + (i + 1).ToString() + " : ";
            lblE.Text = "E-Mail : ";

            //Add the labels and textboxes to the Panel.
            Panel1.Controls.Add(lblU);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxU);

            Panel1.Controls.Add(lblE);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxE);


        }
    }
```

Comment: And what doesn't work? They aren't appeared? What is the question?

Comment: Just tried it on my side and it works fine.

Comment: loses the state, though. i suppose that's your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button"  />
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="Panel1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

and

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //Remove the session when first time page loads.
        Session.Remove("clicks");
        Response.Write(Session["clicks"]);
    }
    else { 
    //initialize a session.
    int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]);

    rowCount++;

    //In each button clic save the numbers into the session.
    Session["clicks"] = rowCount;

        Panel1.Controls.Clear();
    //Create the textboxes and labels each time the button is clicked.
        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            TextBox TxtBoxU = new TextBox();
            TextBox TxtBoxE = new TextBox();

            Label lblU = new Label();
            Label lblE = new Label();

            TxtBoxU.ID = "TextBoxU" + i.ToString();
            TxtBoxE.ID = "TextBoxE" + i.ToString();

            lblU.ID = "LabelU" + i.ToString();
            lblE.ID = "LabelE" + i.ToString();


            lblU.Text = "User " + (i).ToString() + " : ";
            lblE.Text = "E-Mail : ";

            //Add the labels and textboxes to the Panel.
            Panel1.Controls.Add(lblU);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxU);

            Panel1.Controls.Add(lblE);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxE);
        }
    }
}
```